# Return a component instance by key (using Spring.NET Container)

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

Is it possible to return a component instance by key using Spring.NET?

I see the method context.GetObject(string name) but I am not sure if it's the equivalent to Castle Windsor's container.Resolve(string key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that is the equivalent method call